# Why Java Calendar set(int year, int month, int date) not returning correct date?

Tags: java, calendar

According to doc, calendar set() is:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29

```
set(int year, int month, int date) 
Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH.
```

**code:**

```
Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c1.set(2000, 1, 30);  //January 30th 2000
Date sDate = c1.getTime();

System.out.println(sDate);
```

**output:**

```
Wed Mar 01 19:32:21 JST 2000
```

**Why it's not Jan 30 ???**

Comment: Standard suggestion for anyone using `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`: use Joda Time, available at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Months are counted from 0, not 1. Yeah, I know - it's annoying.

Comment: I'll be starting to use jode for every freaking possible project from now on, the amount of inconsistency and weirdness with date and calendar is just too high!

Comment: Always turn off [setLenient()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15336373/4136325)

Comment: @NimChimpsky Java is not so lame anymore. Since Java 8 we’ve got [java.time, the modern and very good Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (also backported to Java 6 and 7).

Answer (score 112, accepted):

1 for month is February. The 30th of February is changed to 1st of March.
You should set 0 for month. The best is to use the constant defined in Calendar:

```
c1.set(2000, Calendar.JANUARY, 30);
```

Comment: Thanks! wish java doc can insists such important point! (or i missed that..?)

Comment: @masato-san: You missed that, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29.

Answer (score 22):

Months in Calendar object start from 0

```
0 = January = Calendar.JANUARY
1 = february = Calendar.FEBRUARY
```

Comment: guy you saved the day

Answer (score 8):

Selected date at the example is interesting. Example code block is:

```
Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c1.set(2000, 1, 30);  //January 30th 2000
Date sDate = c1.getTime();

System.out.println(sDate);
```

and output `Wed Mar 01 19:32:21 JST 2000`.

When I first read the example i think that output is wrong but it is true:)

- `Calendar.Month` is starting from 0 so 1 means February.
- February last day is 28 so output should be 2 March.
- But selected year is important, it is 2000 which means February 29 so result should be 1 March.