# Why does SimpleDateFormat parse incorrect date?

Tags: java, scala

I have date in string format and I want to parse that into util date.

```
var date ="03/11/2013"
```

I am parsing this as :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(date)
```

But the strange thing is that, if I am passing "03-08-**201309 hjhkjhk**" or "03-**88**-2013" or **43**-88-201378", it does not throw error , it parses it.

For this now, I have to write regex pattern for checking whetehr input of date is correct or not.
but why is it so ??

Code :

```
scala> val date="03/88/201309 hjhkjhk"
date: java.lang.String = 03/88/201309 hjhkjhk

scala> new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(date)
res5: java.util.Date = Mon May 27 00:00:00 IST 201309
```

Comment: `var date`? I dont think so, copy your real code into the question please.

Comment: `var date` is not Java.

Comment: @Lutz Horn. I am using scala

Comment: If it's at all an option, you'd probably be better off using Joda Time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You should also look at the Joda Time API which may well allow for a stricter interpretation - and is a generally cleaner date/time API anyway.

Comment: When the question was asked in 2013, Joda-Time was a better option than `SimpleDateFormat` for many purposes. Today (2017) Joda-Time is in maintenance mode, but we have a yet better option in `java.time` AKA JSR-310. I certainly recommend you throw `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` over your shoulder.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You should use `DateFormat.setLenient(false)`:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
df.setLenient(false);
df.parse("03/88/2013"); // Throws an exception
```

I'm not sure that will catch *everything* you want - I seem to remember that even with `setLenient(false)` it's more lenient than you might expect - but it should catch invalid month numbers for example.

I don't think it will catch trailing text, e.g. "03/01/2013 sjsjsj". You could potentially use the overload of `parse` which accepts a `ParsePosition`, then check the current parse index after parsing has completed:

```
ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
Date date = dateFormat.parse(text, position);
if (position.getIndex() != text.length()) {
    // Throw an exception or whatever else you want to do
}
```

You should also look at the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) API which may well allow for a stricter interpretation - and is a generally cleaner date/time API anyway.

Comment: @Rishi: Yes, I was editing my answer to include that part, along with other suggestions. (I've now edited it further.)

Comment: If you want to catch trailing text then you need to use the `parse(String text, ParsePosition pos)` version of the parse method as then you can check whether all input was consumed.

Comment: @Jon Skeet..If I am parsing "03/12/201356", then position.getIndex() and text.length() is same so there is no problem in parsing. but ideally parsing should not be happen. 
I think I should compare with 10 instead of text.length.

Comment: @Rishi: If you've got a fixed format, then yes, it's fine to compare against a fixed length. I can see why "03/12/201356" parses correctly though...

Answer (score 11):

[Jon Skeet’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15336373/5772882) is correct and was a good answer when it was written in 2013.

However, the classes you use in your question, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, are now long outdated, so if someone got a similar issue with them today, IMHO the best answer would be to change to using [the modern Java date & time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

I am sorry I cannot write Scala code, so you will have to live with Java. I am using

```
private static DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

The format pattern letters are the same as in your question, though the meaning is slightly different. `DateTimeFormatter` takes the number of pattern letters literally, as we shall see. Now we try:

```
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(date, parseFormatter));
```

Results:

- `"03/11/2013"` is parsed into `2013-03-11` as expected. I used the modern `LocalDate` class, a class that represents a date without time-of-day, exactly what we need here.
- Passing `"03/88/2013 hjhkjhk"` gives a `DateTimeParseException` with the message `Text '03/88/2013 hjhkjhk' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10`. Pretty precise, isn’t it? The modern API has methods to parse only part of a string if that is what we want, though.
- `"03/88/201309"` gives `Text '03/88/201309' could not be parsed at index 6`. We asked for a 4 digit year and gave it 6 digits, which leads to the objection. Apparently it detects and reports this error before trying to interpret 88 as a day of month.
- It does object to a day of month of 88 too, though: `"03/88/2013"` gives `Text '03/88/2013' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 88`. Again, please enjoy how informative the message is.
- `"03-08-2013"` (with hyphens instead of slashes) gives `Text '03-08-2013' could not be parsed at index 2`, not very surprising. Index 2 is where the first hyphen is.

Jon Skeet explained that the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` can be lenient or non-lenient. This is true for `DateTimeFormatter` too, in fact it has 3 instead of 2 resolver styles, called ‘lenient’, ‘smart’ and ‘strict’. Since many programmers are not aware of this, though, I think they made a good choice of not making ‘lenient’ the default (‘smart’ is).

What if we wanted to make our formatter lenient?

```
private static DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
```

Now it also parses `"03/88/2013"`, into `2013-05-27`. I believe this is what the old class would also have done: counting 88 days from the beginning of March gives May 27. The other error messages are still the same. In other words it still objects to unparsed text, to a 6 digit year and to hyphens.

**Question: Can I use the modern API with my Java version?**

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the new classes (that’s ThreeTen for JSR-310, where the modern API was first defined).
- On Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP, and I think that there’s a wonderful explanation in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).