# Java - Throw error when date is invalid

Tags: java, date-parsing

I have the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatDDMMYYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar quotationDay = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    quotationDay.setTime(formatDDMMYYY.parse("06/13/2015"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Quotation date is in incorrect format.");
}
```

The date "06/13/2015" is incorrect, as there is no 13th month. Java automatically parses it to the next month, in 2016. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening and throw an exception?

Comment: Possibly better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336200/why-does-simpledateformat-parse-incorrect-date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set

```
formatDDMMYYY.setLenient(false);
```

Check the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 3):

You should turn off leniency as stated in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> Leniency
>
> Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient
>   and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a
>   wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar
>   recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the
>   calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient
>   GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as
>   February 1.
>
> When a Calendar is in non-lenient mode, it throws an exception if
>   there is any inconsistency in its calendar fields. For example, a
>   GregorianCalendar always produces DAY_OF_MONTH values between 1 and
>   the length of the month. A non-lenient GregorianCalendar throws an
>   exception upon calculating its time or calendar field values if any
>   out-of-range field value has been set.