# Java Calendar returns wrong month

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want store a date into a Calendar Object, like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 26);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

All values are set correctly, except the month and if I call `cal.getTime()` it returns:

```
Thu Jan 26 10:00:00 CET 2017
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are overriding the month at `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 26);`

Comment: As stated it's working fine.

Comment: Use calendar.Day_OF_MONTH...Day_OF_YEAR will set 26th Jan not JUNE

Comment: FYI: You are using troublesome classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. `OffsetDateTime.of( 2017 , Month.JUNE , 26 , 9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC ) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `DAY_OF_YEAR` you set the number day of the current year.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR

> **DAY_OF_YEAR** Field number for get and set indicating the day number
>   within the current year.

This overrides all sensible configuration like month or year (to current year and month of the number day).

---

So instead of use `DAY_OF_YEAR` you may use `DAY_OF_MONTH` which seems is what you are looking for, this sets the day of the month you set before.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH

> **DAY_OF_MONTH** Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. This is a synonym for DATE. The first day of the month has value 1.

So the configuration you are looking for definetively seems it would be like next:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , 26);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Then when you call getTime you will get:

> Mon Jun 26 11:00:00 CEST 2017

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[Why Java Calendar set(int year, int month, int date) not returning correct date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931955/why-java-calendar-setint-year-int-month-int-date-not-returning-correct-date)" this is an easy way to initialize a Calendar Object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(2017, Calendar.JUNE, 26, 9, 0, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

> Mon Jun 26 11:00:00 CEST 2017

Comment: This could be a comment/suggestion..it's not solving OP's problem

Comment: It does. The code sets the Calendar Object in the desired state.

Comment: Now you’re at it, one may think that [the 6-arg `set` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-int-int-int-) is even more convenient. Then you only need to set the milliseconds spearately.